# ld returned 1 exit status Error

Tags: c++

Cuando compilo y ejecuto el programa me salta el error:

```
ld returned 1 exit status
```

Quisiera ayuda en qué consiste y cómo se arregla el error.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

class Cuenta
{   public:
        Cuenta(int);
        void credito(int);
        void retiro(int);
        int obtenersaldo();
    private:
        int saldo;
};

Cuenta::Cuenta(int inicialsaldo)
{   saldo =0;
    if(inicialsaldo>0){
    saldo =inicialsaldo; }
    else{
        cout<<"error";}
}

void Cuenta::credito(int cantidad){
    saldo =saldo +cantidad;
}

void Cuenta::retiro(int monto){
    if(monto>saldo){
        cout<<"error";
    }
    else{
        saldo =saldo -monto;
    }
}

int Cuenta::obtenersaldo()
{
    return saldo;
}
```

Comment: `ld returned 1 exit status` no dice mucho sobre qué es el error, ¿te sale algun otro mensaje de error? si es así agregalo a la pregunta.

Comment: tienes dos `#include` al principio, lo mismo es por eso

Answer (score 0, accepted):

para empezar, `ld returned 1 exit status`, significa, que ocurrio un error al momento de "enlazar" el ejecutable de tu programa, porque, posiblemente falta una `referencia`.

Por los datos que nos das, lo más probable, es que el error, se deba a la ausencia del punto de entrada de tu aplicación, es decir, la función `main`.

```c
int main()
{
    // Todo el código que se va a ejecutar va aquí
    return 0;
}
```

En otro caso..

Quizá tu archivo es parte de un programa más grande. En ese caso, tienes que asegurarte (en caso de que estes usando la linea de comandos) de elegir el compilador para C++! Es mucho, muy importante. Claro, esto puede ser posible si estás usando, por ejemplo `gcc`. Ya que el compilador no va a vincular las librerías de C++ (`iostream` por ejemplo).

Para finalizar, si estás utilizando C++, te recomiendo que (si no es obligatorio claro), utilizar el manejo de memoria que C++ ya provee (operadores `new` y `delete`)

Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Por la otra pregunta que has puesto te puedo decir que falta la función "entry point", que en el caso de una aplicación Windows es `WinMain`.

Si estás haciendo un programa de consola o una librería debes cambiar los settings correspondientes en el entorno de compilación.

Answer (score 0):

Cuando te salta el error : `ld returned 1 exit status` es consecuencia de problemas previos en la cual no está ligado/enlazado a dicho ejecutable.
En tu caso no tienes la función `main`

```
int main(){


  return 0;
}
```