# Error Id returned 1 exit status

Tags: c

Estoy realizando un codigo usando programacion modular el codigo es el siguiente:

```
#include <stdio.h>  //printf()  scanf()
#include <conio.h>  //getch()

int suma (int a , int b);

main(){

//variables
int PValor=0, SValor=0,ValorC=0;

//entradas
printf("\n Digite primer valor: ");
scanf("%d",&PValor);

printf("\n Digite segundo valor: ");
scanf("%d",&SValor);

//procesos
ValorC=suma(PValor,SValor);

//salidas
printf("\n La suma es: %d",ValorC);
getch();

}

int suma (int a , int b){
int c=0;
c=a+b;
return(c);
}
```

Sigo todas las indicacion que me dio mi docente pero al momento de compilar me salta un error de Id returned 1 exit status, nose porque sale este error, yo veo que el codigo es correcto. Alguien que pueda resolver esta duda.

Comment: entra aqui https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/376192/ld-returned-1-exit-status-error#:~:text=para%20empezar%2C%20ld%20returned%201%20exit%20status%2C%20significa%2C,de%20tu%20aplicaci%C3%B3n%2C%20es%20decir%2C%20la%20funci%C3%B3n%20main.

Comment: El código funciona, revisa donde estas guardando el proyecto y donde ese encuentra el main.

Comment: `ld` es el linker. Si el exit status es `1`, hubo un error. No podemos extraer mas información con lo que compartes, puedes compartir el error completo?